# javascript prevent space button to be typed

Tags: javascript, textfield

how can i prevent the user from further typing in the text-field once he/she has typed space character in the field? i tried following few lines of codes but it didn't work... any idea why???

**HTML**

```
<input id="username" type="text" onkeyup="abc(event);" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function abc(event){
   for(i=0;i<document.getElementById("username").value.length;i++){
      if(document.getElementById("username").value.charCodeAt(i) == 32){
         event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: For readability, consider using `indexOf` or `match` to determine whether the value contains a space, rather than looping through the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the use of space by adding this listener to your input.

```
function preventSpace(e) {
   var char = e.which || e.charCode;
   if(char == 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="username" type="text" onkeypress="preventSpace(event);" />
```

Comment: thanks ... dude now it is working .. by adding onkeypress event listener

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`event.stopPropagation();`

Your listener is a mess, try this instead:

```
  function abc(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 32) {
      console.log("space");
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

You should also listen for either `keypress` or `keydown`.

Comment: thanks for answering .. bro .. it was just my event listener .. changed from onkeyup tp keypress.. now it's perfectly working